# Print out in a java web application

Tags: jsp, servlets, printing, reporting

I have a web app for restaurant order management build using servlet/jsp.

I have a screen which displays orders under different categories like Food,Wine etc..

I want to

1) Take print out of order
2) If possible send print job to different printer depending on categories

First i tried using Java script window.print and a different template for print, but this isnt working that great for me.

Is there any java api/ **free** reporting framework which can allow this.?

Hope this makes sense..
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what exactly "wasn't working that great".  But I would recommend the following:

1) Your .jsp should provide a "Print" link that opens an HTML/CSS/Javascript window containing just the parts you want to print

2) Your web app should have some CSS specifically for "print" media:

- http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/a/aa042103a.htm

3) Here are some additional tips for using Javascript "window.print()":

- http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471121/Print-a-Web-Page-Using-JavaScript.htm

I would discourage you from investing time and efford in a "new framework" - this is really just Web Design 101.  IMHO...

Comment: I want to take print-out in a thermal printer,with KOT like paper layout.So it was difficult in setting out dimensions to exactly fix it. But i think with little extra work approach suggested by you will just be fine.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a PDF report using Jasper Reports or BIRT (I'm sure there are other options, but I know about these ones). You won't be able to automatically choose or suggest a printer, though. That's out of the control of the server.

Comment: thanks! what if i connect printers to server itself, like a LAN application with a local server? Will i then be able to suggest a printer.